# EC2 Instance, mount volume DOS/MBR boot sector

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server, ext4

I'm trying to mount the main /dev/sda1 volumen from an EC2 instance, to a new one, but I have these issues:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdg /mnt/xvdg/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdg,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

**info from dmesg:**

```
$ dmesg | tail
[  673.481965]  xvdg: xvdg1
[  673.589140]  xvdg: xvdg1
[  673.711554]  xvdg: xvdg1
[  673.802113]  xvdg: xvdg1
[  673.872627]  xvdg: xvdg1
[  673.978105]  xvdg: xvdg1
[10382.432880] EXT4-fs (xvdg): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

**More info:**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/xvdg
Disk /dev/xvdg: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/xvdg1 *    16065 33543719 33527655  16G 83 Linux
Looking for more info, got to this link
```

I also followed [these steps](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/) to Repair a broken Ext4 Superblock. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 20):

The disk is partitioned, use this instead:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/xvdg1 /mnt/xvdg/
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you - that '1' was the bit I needed.